# Como dar um INSERT de chaves primárias de uma tabela X em uma tabela Y

Tags: mysql, sql

Olá, bom, estou com uma dificuldade ao dar insert na tabela divida, sendo que nela eu tenho duas FK's que ligam a tabela pessoa.. Minha dúvida é o seguinte: Como fazer para pegar as PK's desejadas e inserir como FK's?

Tabela divida:

```
create table divida(
codigo_divida int(5) primary key auto_increment,
credor int(5) not null,
foreign key (credor) references pessoa(id_cliente),
data_atualizacao date not null,
valor_divida float not null,
devedor int(5) not null,
foreign key (devedor) references pessoa(id_cliente)
);
```

Tabela pessoa:

```
create table pessoa
(id_cliente int(5) primary key auto_increment,
nome_cliente varchar(45) not null,
tipo varchar(10) not null,
telefone varchar(20) null,
documento varchar(25) not null,
endereco int(5),
foreign key (endereco) references endereco(endereco_id),
e_mail varchar(45) null,
unique(documento, e_mail)
);
```

Qualquer ajuda vai ser bem vida, agradeço a todos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, consegui o que queria!

Aqui vai a minha solução:

Criei uma função que ao digitar o cpf (coluna documento em pessoa) ele retornasse o id da pessoa em si, e dei um insert com essa função.

(Fiz isso do cpf para ficar mais intuitivo pro usuário)

Função:

```
delimiter $$
create function executaBusca(doc varchar(25)) 
returns int
deterministic
begin
    declare idBuscado int;
    set idBuscado = (select id_cliente from pessoa where documento = doc);
    return idBuscado;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Insert:

```
insert into divida (codigo_divida, credor, devedor, valor_divida) values (default, executaBusca("valor do cpf"), executaBusca("valor do cpf"), 1555.00);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode pegar os códigos inseridos enquanto inclui na tabela usando `LAST_INSERT_ID`. Por exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO pessoa ...

SET @id_cliente = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

E depois usar as variáveis que foram obtidas para inserir na outra tabela

```
INSERT INTO divida(id_cliente , ...) values(@id_cliente , ...)
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback, porém nesse caso, não é funcional! Eu queria inserir um ID qualquer, sem ser necessariamente o último.. entende?
Se conseguir me dar uma luz agradeço muito!